# splitting a pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to filter and split my original dataframe into a number of dataframes using the condition that progressPercentage goes from 1.0 to 100 as in the following example:

Input:

```
id_B, ts_B,course,weight,Phase,remainingTime,progressPercentage
id1,2017-04-27 01:35:30,cotton,3.5,A,01:15:00,23.0
id1,2017-04-27 01:37:30,cotton,3.5,B,01:13:00,24.0
id1,2017-04-27 01:38:00,cotton,3.5,B,01:13:00,24.0
id1,2017-04-27 01:38:30,cotton,3.5,C,01:13:00,24.0
id1,2017-04-27 01:39:00,cotton,3.5,C,00:02:00,99.0
id1,2017-04-27 01:39:30,cotton,3.5,C,00:01:00,100.0
id1,2017-04-27 01:40:00,cotton,3.5,Finish,00:01:00,100.0
id1,2017-04-27 02:35:30,cotton,3.5,A,03:15:00,1.0
id1,2017-04-27 02:36:00,cotton,3.5,A,03:14:00,2.0  
id1,2017-04-27 02:36:30,cotton,3.5,A,03:14:00,2.0 
id1,2017-04-27 02:37:00,cotton,3.5,B,03:13:00,3.0
id1,2017-04-27 02:37:30,cotton,3.5,B,03:13:00,4.0
id1,2017-04-27 02:38:00,cotton,3.5,B,03:13:00,5.0
id1,2017-04-27 02:38:30,cotton,3.5,C,03:13:00,98.0
id1,2017-04-27 02:39:00,cotton,3.5,C,00:02:00,99.0
id1,2017-04-27 02:39:30,cotton,3.5,C,00:01:00,100.0
id1,2017-04-27 02:40:00,cotton,3.5,Finish,00:01:00,100.0
id2,2017-04-27 03:36:00,cotton,3.5,A,03:15:00,1.0
id2,2017-04-27 03:36:30,cotton,3.5,A,03:14:00,1.0 
id2,2017-04-27 03:37:00,cotton,3.5,B,03:13:00,2.0
id2,2017-04-27 03:37:30,cotton,3.5,B,03:13:00,2.0
id2,2017-04-27 03:38:00,cotton,3.5,B,03:13:00,3.0
id2,2017-04-27 03:38:30,cotton,3.5,C,03:13:00,98.0
id2,2017-04-27 03:39:00,cotton,3.5,C,00:02:00,99.0
id2,2017-04-27 03:39:30,cotton,3.5,C,00:01:00,100.0
id2,2017-04-27 03:40:00,cotton,3.5,Finish,00:01:00,100.0
id1,2017-05-27 01:35:30,cotton,3.5,A,03:15:00,23.0
id1,2017-05-27 01:37:30,cotton,3.5,B,03:13:00,24.0
id1,2017-05-27 01:38:00,cotton,3.5,B,03:13:00,24.0
id1,2017-05-27 01:38:30,cotton,3.5,C,03:13:00,24.0
id1,2017-05-27 01:39:00,cotton,3.5,C,00:02:00,99.0
id1,2017-05-27 01:39:30,cotton,3.5,C,00:01:00,100.0
id1,2017-05-27 01:40:00,cotton,3.5,Finish,00:01:00,100.0
id1,2017-05-27 02:35:30,cotton,3.5,A,01:15:00,1.0
id1,2017-05-27 02:36:00,cotton,3.5,A,01:14:00,2.0  
id1,2017-05-27 02:36:30,cotton,3.5,A,01:13:00,2.0 
id1,2017-05-27 02:37:00,cotton,3.5,B,01:12:00,3.0
id1,2017-05-27 02:37:30,cotton,3.5,B,01:11:00,4.0
id1,2017-05-27 02:38:00,cotton,3.5,B,01:10:00,5.0
id1,2017-05-27 02:38:30,cotton,3.5,C,01:09:00,98.0
id1,2017-05-27 02:39:00,cotton,3.5,C,00:08:00,99.0
```

Outputs:

```
id_B, ts_B,course,weight,Phase,remainingTime,progressPercentage
id1,2017-04-27 01:35:30,cotton,3.5,A,01:15:00,23.0
id1,2017-04-27 01:37:30,cotton,3.5,B,01:13:00,24.0
id1,2017-04-27 01:38:00,cotton,3.5,B,01:13:00,24.0
id1,2017-04-27 01:38:30,cotton,3.5,C,01:13:00,24.0
id1,2017-04-27 01:39:00,cotton,3.5,C,00:02:00,99.0
id1,2017-04-27 01:39:30,cotton,3.5,C,00:01:00,100.0
id1,2017-04-27 01:40:00,cotton,3.5,Finish,00:01:00,100.0

id_B, ts_B,course,weight,Phase,remainingTime,progressPercentage
id1,2017-04-27 02:35:30,cotton,3.5,A,03:15:00,1.0
id1,2017-04-27 02:36:00,cotton,3.5,A,03:14:00,2.0  
id1,2017-04-27 02:36:30,cotton,3.5,A,03:14:00,2.0 
id1,2017-04-27 02:37:00,cotton,3.5,B,03:13:00,3.0
id1,2017-04-27 02:37:30,cotton,3.5,B,03:13:00,4.0
id1,2017-04-27 02:38:00,cotton,3.5,B,03:13:00,5.0
id1,2017-04-27 02:38:30,cotton,3.5,C,03:13:00,98.0
id1,2017-04-27 02:39:00,cotton,3.5,C,00:02:00,99.0
id1,2017-04-27 02:39:30,cotton,3.5,C,00:01:00,100.0
id1,2017-04-27 02:40:00,cotton,3.5,Finish,00:01:00,100.0

id_B, ts_B,course,weight,Phase,remainingTime,progressPercentage
id2,2017-04-27 03:36:00,cotton,3.5,A,03:15:00,1.0
id2,2017-04-27 03:36:30,cotton,3.5,A,03:14:00,1.0 
id2,2017-04-27 03:37:00,cotton,3.5,B,03:13:00,2.0
id2,2017-04-27 03:37:30,cotton,3.5,B,03:13:00,2.0
id2,2017-04-27 03:38:00,cotton,3.5,B,03:13:00,3.0
id2,2017-04-27 03:38:30,cotton,3.5,C,03:13:00,98.0
id2,2017-04-27 03:39:00,cotton,3.5,C,00:02:00,99.0
id2,2017-04-27 03:39:30,cotton,3.5,C,00:01:00,100.0
id2,2017-04-27 03:40:00,cotton,3.5,Finish,00:01:00,100.0

id_B, ts_B,course,weight,Phase,remainingTime,progressPercentage
id1,2017-05-27 01:35:30,cotton,3.5,A,03:15:00,1.0
id1,2017-05-27 01:37:30,cotton,3.5,B,03:13:00,2.0
id1,2017-05-27 01:38:00,cotton,3.5,B,03:13:00,3.0
id1,2017-05-27 01:38:30,cotton,3.5,C,03:13:00,4.0
id1,2017-05-27 01:39:00,cotton,3.5,C,00:02:00,99.0
id1,2017-05-27 01:39:30,cotton,3.5,C,00:01:00,100.0
id1,2017-05-27 01:40:00,cotton,3.5,Finish,00:01:00,100.0

id_B, ts_B,course,weight,Phase,remainingTime,progressPercentage
id1,2017-05-27 02:35:30,cotton,3.5,A,01:15:00,1.0
id1,2017-05-27 02:36:00,cotton,3.5,A,01:14:00,2.0  
id1,2017-05-27 02:36:30,cotton,3.5,A,01:13:00,2.0 
id1,2017-05-27 02:37:00,cotton,3.5,B,01:12:00,3.0
id1,2017-05-27 02:37:30,cotton,3.5,B,01:11:00,4.0
id1,2017-05-27 02:38:00,cotton,3.5,B,01:10:00,5.0
id1,2017-05-27 02:38:30,cotton,3.5,C,01:09:00,98.0
id1,2017-05-27 02:39:00,cotton,3.5,C,00:08:00,99.0
id1,2017-05-27 02:39:00,cotton,3.5,C,00:01:00,100.0
```

I have been using the  .shift() and groupby as in the following:

```
 a = dfb['Operation.progressPercentage'].shift().eq(100)
 grouping = dfb.groupby([dfb.wm_id,a])
```

but it did not provide  the expected results. 
Please, any help on how I should change the code to get it done?

Many Thanks in advance.
Best Regards,
Carlo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `Finish` value sometimes missing and need use only `progressPercentage` column use:

```
shifted = df['progressPercentage'].shift()
#compare difference for second 100 if together 100 (e.g. 15, 16 row)   
m = shifted.diff(-1).ne(0) & shifted.eq(100)
a = m.cumsum()

aa = df.groupby([df.id_B,a])

for k, gp in aa: 
    print('key=' + str(k))
    print(gp)
    print('A NEW ONE...')
```

---

```
key=('id1', 0)
  id_B                 ts_B  course  weight   Phase remainingTime  \
0  id1  2017-04-27 01:35:30  cotton     3.5       A      01:15:00   
1  id1  2017-04-27 01:37:30  cotton     3.5       B      01:13:00   
2  id1  2017-04-27 01:38:00  cotton     3.5       B      01:13:00   
3  id1  2017-04-27 01:38:30  cotton     3.5       C      01:13:00   
4  id1  2017-04-27 01:39:00  cotton     3.5       C      00:02:00   
5  id1  2017-04-27 01:39:30  cotton     3.5       C      00:01:00   
6  id1  2017-04-27 01:40:00  cotton     3.5  Finish      00:01:00   

   progressPercentage  
0                23.0  
1                24.0  
2                24.0  
3                24.0  
4                99.0  
5               100.0  
6               100.0  
A NEW ONE...
key=('id1', 1)
   id_B                 ts_B  course  weight   Phase remainingTime  \
7   id1  2017-04-27 02:35:30  cotton     3.5       A      03:15:00   
8   id1  2017-04-27 02:36:00  cotton     3.5       A      03:14:00   
9   id1  2017-04-27 02:36:30  cotton     3.5       A      03:14:00   
10  id1  2017-04-27 02:37:00  cotton     3.5       B      03:13:00   
11  id1  2017-04-27 02:37:30  cotton     3.5       B      03:13:00   
12  id1  2017-04-27 02:38:00  cotton     3.5       B      03:13:00   
13  id1  2017-04-27 02:38:30  cotton     3.5       C      03:13:00   
14  id1  2017-04-27 02:39:00  cotton     3.5       C      00:02:00   
15  id1  2017-04-27 02:39:30  cotton     3.5       C      00:01:00   
16  id1  2017-04-27 02:40:00  cotton     3.5  Finish      00:01:00   

    progressPercentage  
7                  1.0  
8                  2.0  
9                  2.0  
10                 3.0  
11                 4.0  
12                 5.0  
13                98.0  
14                99.0  
15               100.0  
16               100.0  
A NEW ONE...
key=('id2', 2)

...
```

Comment: It is working. Many Thanks Jezrael. Actually my solution is very close to yours and based on the previous feedback you gave. Thanks.

Comment: Super, glad you help.

Comment: This is much neater. Plus one sir

Comment: given the above output, May I ask please: how to count for each id how many dataset I got? in our example, id1=4 and id2=1

Comment: You can use `print (df.id_B.value_counts())`

Answer (score 2):

You can divide the dataframe by progressPercentage which is equal 100. Remove the earlier index if they are consecutive.Then slice and append the dataframe to an array. Hope this helps

```
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_csv('input.csv',delimiter=',') # The input csv provided
df1 = df[(df["progressPercentage "]==100)]
x = (np.array(df1.index) + 1).tolist()
x.insert(0,0)
#Remove the consecutive elements so that they can be treated under one dataframe. 
x = [ begin for begin, end in zip(x, x[1:]) if (begin != end-1)]
x.insert(len(x),df.shape[0])
frames = [df.iloc[begin:end] for begin, end in zip(x, x[1:])]
```

You can print the dataframes using a for loop, i.e

```
for df in frames:
    print(df)
```

Output of the dataframes:

```
  id_B                 ts_B  course  weight   Phase remainingTime  \
0  id1  2017-04-27 01:35:30  cotton     3.5       A      01:15:00   
1  id1  2017-04-27 01:37:30  cotton     3.5       B      01:13:00   
2  id1  2017-04-27 01:38:00  cotton     3.5       B      01:13:00   
3  id1  2017-04-27 01:38:30  cotton     3.5       C      01:13:00   
4  id1  2017-04-27 01:39:00  cotton     3.5       C      00:02:00   
5  id1  2017-04-27 01:39:30  cotton     3.5       C      00:01:00   
6  id1  2017-04-27 01:40:00  cotton     3.5  Finish      00:01:00   

   progressPercentage   
0                 23.0  
1                 24.0  
2                 24.0  
3                 24.0  
4                 99.0  
5                100.0  
6                100.0  
   id_B                 ts_B  course  weight   Phase remainingTime  \
7   id1  2017-04-27 02:35:30  cotton     3.5       A      03:15:00   
8   id1  2017-04-27 02:36:00  cotton     3.5       A      03:14:00   
9   id1  2017-04-27 02:36:30  cotton     3.5       A      03:14:00   
10  id1  2017-04-27 02:37:00  cotton     3.5       B      03:13:00   
11  id1  2017-04-27 02:37:30  cotton     3.5       B      03:13:00   
12  id1  2017-04-27 02:38:00  cotton     3.5       B      03:13:00   
13  id1  2017-04-27 02:38:30  cotton     3.5       C      03:13:00   
14  id1  2017-04-27 02:39:00  cotton     3.5       C      00:02:00   
15  id1  2017-04-27 02:39:30  cotton     3.5       C      00:01:00   
16  id1  2017-04-27 02:40:00  cotton     3.5  Finish      00:01:00   

    progressPercentage   
7                   1.0  
8                   2.0  
9                   2.0  
10                  3.0  
11                  4.0  
12                  5.0  
13                 98.0  
14                 99.0  
15                100.0  
16                100.0  
   id_B                 ts_B  course  weight   Phase remainingTime  \
17  id2  2017-04-27 03:36:00  cotton     3.5       A      03:15:00   
18  id2  2017-04-27 03:36:30  cotton     3.5       A      03:14:00   
19  id2  2017-04-27 03:37:00  cotton     3.5       B      03:13:00   
20  id2  2017-04-27 03:37:30  cotton     3.5       B      03:13:00   
21  id2  2017-04-27 03:38:00  cotton     3.5       B      03:13:00   
22  id2  2017-04-27 03:38:30  cotton     3.5       C      03:13:00   
23  id2  2017-04-27 03:39:00  cotton     3.5       C      00:02:00   
24  id2  2017-04-27 03:39:30  cotton     3.5       C      00:01:00   
25  id2  2017-04-27 03:40:00  cotton     3.5  Finish      00:01:00   

    progressPercentage   
17                  1.0  
18                  1.0  
19                  2.0  
20                  2.0  
21                  3.0  
22                 98.0  
23                 99.0  
24                100.0  
25                100.0  
   id_B                 ts_B  course  weight   Phase remainingTime  \
26  id1  2017-05-27 01:35:30  cotton     3.5       A      03:15:00   
27  id1  2017-05-27 01:37:30  cotton     3.5       B      03:13:00   
28  id1  2017-05-27 01:38:00  cotton     3.5       B      03:13:00   
29  id1  2017-05-27 01:38:30  cotton     3.5       C      03:13:00   
30  id1  2017-05-27 01:39:00  cotton     3.5       C      00:02:00   
31  id1  2017-05-27 01:39:30  cotton     3.5       C      00:01:00   
32  id1  2017-05-27 01:40:00  cotton     3.5  Finish      00:01:00   

    progressPercentage   
26                 23.0  
27                 24.0  
28                 24.0  
29                 24.0  
30                 99.0  
31                100.0  
32                100.0  
   id_B                 ts_B  course  weight Phase remainingTime  \
33  id1  2017-05-27 02:35:30  cotton     3.5     A      01:15:00   
34  id1  2017-05-27 02:36:00  cotton     3.5     A      01:14:00   
35  id1  2017-05-27 02:36:30  cotton     3.5     A      01:13:00   
36  id1  2017-05-27 02:37:00  cotton     3.5     B      01:12:00   
37  id1  2017-05-27 02:37:30  cotton     3.5     B      01:11:00   
38  id1  2017-05-27 02:38:00  cotton     3.5     B      01:10:00   
39  id1  2017-05-27 02:38:30  cotton     3.5     C      01:09:00   
40  id1  2017-05-27 02:39:00  cotton     3.5     C      00:08:00   
41  id1  2017-05-27 02:39:00  cotton     3.5     C      00:08:00   

    progressPercentage   
33                  1.0  
34                  2.0  
35                  2.0  
36                  3.0  
37                  4.0  
38                  5.0  
39                 98.0  
40                 99.0  
41                100.0  
   id_B                 ts_B  course  weight   Phase remainingTime  \
42  id2  2017-04-27 03:36:00  cotton     3.5       A      03:15:00   
43  id2  2017-04-27 03:36:30  cotton     3.5       A      03:14:00   
44  id2  2017-04-27 03:37:00  cotton     3.5       B      03:13:00   
45  id2  2017-04-27 03:37:30  cotton     3.5       B      03:13:00   
46  id2  2017-04-27 03:38:00  cotton     3.5       B      03:13:00   
47  id2  2017-04-27 03:38:30  cotton     3.5       C      03:13:00   
48  id2  2017-04-27 03:39:00  cotton     3.5       C      00:02:00   
49  id2  2017-04-27 03:39:30  cotton     3.5       C      00:01:00   
50  id2  2017-04-27 03:40:00  cotton     3.5  Finish      00:01:00   

    progressPercentage   
42                  1.0  
43                  1.0  
44                  2.0  
45                  2.0  
46                  3.0  
47                 98.0  
48                 99.0  
49                100.0  
50                100.0
```

Comment: Thank you Bharath. I am going to check your solution with the one I designed:         a = dfb['Operation.progressPercentage'].shift().eq(100).cumsum()
        
        df_output = dfb.groupby([dfb.wm_id,a])

Comment: However, the word Finish is not alway present.

Comment: I changed your solution as df1 = dfb[dfb['Operation.progressPercentage'] == 100]

Comment: Just finished running and, it did not work. What do you mean to use '40:00' as the end of the dataframe? As you can see, I need to separate one experiment from the other and, it finish when the percentage is 100%.

Comment: Well, it is not possible because it can be different in each experiment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150206/discussion-between-bharath-shetty-and-carlo-allocca).

Answer (score 0):

the best way I found is the following:

```
    a = dfb['progressPercentage'].shift().eq(100).cumsum()
    df_output = dfb.groupby([dfb.id_B,a])

    for k, gp in aa: 
        print('key=' + str(k))
        print(gp.sort_values(['eventTime', 'wm_id'], ascending=[1, 0]).to_string())
        print('A NEW ONE...')
```

Comment: *eventTime'= ts_B and  'wm_id'=id_B

Comment: whats `aa` in that for loop

Comment: aa is the df_output